# Write delphi function in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, syntax, plsql

How to write the equivalent PL/SQL function from this Delphi function:

```
Function TConvert.MGRS(lat : Double; Lon : Double; a : Double; 
         InverseFlattening : Double; Coding:Integer; Digits : Integer) : String ;
var
 UTMs1 : String;
 E1 : Double;
 N1 : Double;
 Zn : Integer;
 Lzn : String;
 Sq : String;
begin
 UTMs1 := UTM(lat, Lon, a, InverseFlattening) ;
 E1 := UTMX(UTMs1);
 N1 := UTMY(UTMs1);
 Zn := UTMZone(lat, Lon);
 Lzn := MGRSLatZone(lat);
 Sq := SquareID(Zn, N1, E1, Coding);
 Result := Format('%.2d', [Zn] )  + Lzn + Sq +
     Copy(Format('%.5d',[Round(E1 - 100000 * Trunc(E1 / 100000))]), 1, Digits) +
     Copy(Format('%.5d',[Round(N1 - 100000 * Trunc(N1 / 100000))]), 1, Digits);
end;
```

MGRS(0, 0, 6378.137, 298.2572236, 1, 5) = 31NAA6602100000

Comment: Please supply full function definition with parameters.

Comment: Some samples of expected inputs and output would also be useful.

Comment: Do you know any PL/SQL? Have you tried to write any code? Do you understand what this code does?

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes I know some PL/SQL. Yes, almost done writing. Yes, but I am not able to understand how to format it in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if entire code may be translated to native Oracle calls, but regarding initial question about string formatting resulting code may look like this:

```
create or replace function MyFunction(
  Zn     in number,
  Lzn    in varchar2,
  Sq     in varchar2,
  E1     in number,
  N1     in number,
  Digits in number
) 
return varchar2
as
  vRes varchar2(4000);
begin

  vRes := trim(to_char(Zn,'999999999999999999.00')) || LZn || Sq || 
          substr(trim(to_char(round(E1 - 100000 * trunc(E1/100000)),'999999999999999999.00000')), 1, Digits) || 
          substr(trim(to_char(round(N1 - 100000 * trunc(N1/100000)),'999999999999999999.00000')), 1, Digits) 
  ;

  return vRes;

end;
```

[<kbd>**SQLFiddle test**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ea7c/2)

[Oracle format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

[TO_CHAR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm)

[TRUNC()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm)

[TRIM()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm)

[Google](http://www.google.com) ;)

Comment: Thank you.  You got a few seconds ahead of me, I was about to answer my own question with something like:
RT*M http://letmegooglethatforyou.com/?q=pl/sql+format+mask

Comment: @writtrup Ok :) Note that number formats always return leading blank, so you need trim output.

Comment: Complete code can be reviewed here:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71387/test-of-oracle-db-functions-converting-lat-long-to-utm-and-mgrs-with-real-data-k
Thank you @ThinkJet